# In Maven, what is the difference between an extension and a plugin

Tags: maven

What is the functional difference between an extension and a plugin in Maven?

The below examples are taken from [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html) which provides a brief summary but doesn't explain the difference well.

Extension example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Plugin example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From the docs:](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Extensions)

> Extensions are a list of artifacts that are to be used in this build.
>   They will be included in the running build's classpath. They can
>   enable extensions to the build process (such as add an ftp provider
>   for the Wagon transport mechanism), as well as make plugins active
>   which make changes to the build lifecycle. In short, extensions are
>   artifacts that activated during build. The extensions do not have to
>   actually do anything nor contain a Mojo. For this reason, extensions
>   are excellent for specifying one out of multiple implementations of a
>   common plugin interface.

The above are usually call build extensions which are often use the `org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant` for particular usage.

A plugin which is defined with

```xml
<extension>true</extension>
```

will usually define it's own life cycle or [packaging types](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-3.3.0/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml?view=markup) like the maven-bundle-plugin which makes it possible to define a `<packaging>bundle</packaging>` or Maven Tycho defines packaging types: `<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>`.